# Windows Authentication via SSMS to SQL Server on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, ssms, windows-authentication

I have successfully setup SQL on Linux and configured Windows Authentication. I am able to use my AD account when on the local box and using SQLCMD. However when I attempt to use SSMS from a bastion host, I get logon denied because of an untrusted domain. Even though the Linux server is joined to the same domain. I have not found any information so far so asking here. [image]

Comment: How did you join the Linux box to the domain? It requires Kerberos to be set up.

Comment: I used realm join. I followed instructions from here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/deploying-and-configuring-active-directory-authentication-with-sql-server-2017-on-amazon-linux-2/

Comment: So the bastion host is on the same domain as the Linux box, and both have line-of-sight (direct) network connection to a domain controller? Are you logged in to a domain user on the bastion when running SSMS?

Comment: Yes. They are both on the same domain. They can communicate as I can login using the SA account from the bastion host. I am logged into the box with my domain credentials and running SSMS